# Question related to array

Tags: php

I'm trying to print array. All code working fine.But at last I'm getting `ArrayArray'. Can any one solve this problem. many many thanks

here is my array

```
Array
(
[Post1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [title] => hi
    )
[Post2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
            )
    )
[Post3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
            )
    )
 )
```

Here is my PHP Code

```
foreach($post as $key => $value) {
 foreach($value as $print => $key) {
     echo "<br>".$key;
   }
}
```

here is output

```
ID
Array
Array
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($post as $key => $value) {
 foreach($value as $print => $key) {
     if (is_array($key)){
         foreach($key as $print2 => $key2) {
          echo "<br>".$key2;
          }

     }else{
     echo "<br>".$key;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks. Is it possible to print particular key? example `----------   foreach($key as $print2 => $key2) {
          echo "<br>".$key2['id'];
          }------`

Comment: @user559744 You can use your method as long as `$key2` is an array which has the key `id` specified.

Answer (score 0):

The *to string* method of an array is to return `"Array"`.

It sounds like you want to view the array for debugging purposes. `var_dump()` is your friend :)

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to print an array, resulting in `Array`.
If you want to print an array use `print_r`

Answer (score 0):

I think the trouble for you is that you have $key in the outer loop and $key in the inner loop so its really confusing which $key you are talking about for starters.

You just want the stuff printed out to debug?

```
echo "<pre>" . print_r( $post , true ) . "</pre>\n";
```